# Approximation of Dynmical System

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, approximation, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose I have a discrete dynamical system given by:
$$
X^{n+1} = f(X^{n})
\qquad X^0 =x
,
$$
where $f$ is some diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.  When does there exist a function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ such that:

$$
Z^{n+1}= Z^{n} + \tilde{f}(Z^{n})  \qquad Z^0=x,
$$

and (either of):

---

*Not Ideally:*

---

and for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $n_{\epsilon}>0$ satisfying:
$$
\|Z^n - X^n\|<\epsilon \qquad (\forall n\geq n_{\epsilon})?
$$

---

### *Ideally:*

Or it possible, the stronger condition holds:
$X^n = Z^n$ for all large $n$?

Comment: Should that be $Z^{n+1}= X^{n+1} + \tilde{f}(Z^{n})$?

Comment: Nope, it should be $Z^{n+1}= Z^{n} + \tilde{f}(Z^{n})$.

Comment: Why not simply define $\tilde f(x) = f(x) - x$ to get $Z^n = X^n$, then?

Comment: True!  I'd accept that as an answer.  Also, if you're interested in answering the stochastic version of there question; here it is:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350990/probabilistic-approximation-of-non-linear-dynamical-system-by-diffusion-process#350990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to take $\tilde f(x) = f(x) - x$, which leads to $Z^n = X^n$ for all $n$.